# Set mutiple properties of an object in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, perfmon

I would like to set multiple properties for data collector set object in powershell. How can I do that,

Here is the code I was trying that fails.

```
$hash_table=@{
        DisplayName = "Test"
        RootPath = "C:\Test"
        Segment = -1
        SegmentMaxDuration = 600
        SegmentMaxSize = 0
        SubdirectoryFormat = 1
    }
$dcs = New-Object -COM Pla.DataCollectorSet @hash_table
```

Error Details:

```
   New-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DisplayName'.
At line:9 char:45
+ $dcs = New-Object -COM Pla.DataCollectorSet @hash_table
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Any better ways of setting all required properties at once instead of setting them one by one?

Comment: "the code I was trying that fails." - how does it fail? Please post any errors you get

Comment: For starters, `$hash_table==@{` is invalid, should only be 1 `=`

Comment: Added exception details & the assignment operator was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't splat object properties like this, what your current code does is try to pass the hashtable parameters as parameters to `New-Object`, not to the COM object you are trying to instantiate. What you want to do is use the `-Property` parameter to set the properties you've named in the hashtable on the object. This should work for you:

```
$hash_table=@{
        DisplayName = "Test"
        RootPath = "C:\Test"
        Segment = -1
        SegmentMaxDuration = 600
        SegmentMaxSize = 0
        SubdirectoryFormat = 1
}
$dcs = New-Object -COM Pla.DataCollectorSet -Property $hash_table
```

If you wanted to use splatting for the `New-Object` parameters, your code would need to look more like this:

```
$hash_table=@{
    COMObject = 'Pla.DataCollectorSet'
    Property = @{
        DisplayName = "Test"
        RootPath = "C:\Test"
        Segment = -1
        SegmentMaxDuration = 600
        SegmentMaxSize = 0
        SubdirectoryFormat = 1
    }
}
$dcs = New-Object @hash_table
```

See [this example from Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?view=powershell-7#example-2--create-an-internet-explorer-com-object) on `New-Object` for more information.

Comment: that works & thank for pointing me to the right source.

Comment: Once this object is created I'm trying to create an instance for a collector & set properties for that. Is there a similar way I can set those properties?
$dcs = New-Object @hash_table
$dc = $dcs.DataCollectors.CreateDataCollector(0)
Once the $dc instance is created I would like to set properties for that instead of assigning one by one. can you suggest?

Comment: Unfortunately, if the class doesn't provide a way to set multiple properties at once via an instance method or constructor, you will have to set them one by one. You may be able to use a loop or something to do this, but there's no "PS magic" here that I'm aware of.